# Should electronic games be included the site's purview?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Generalizing the [pinball discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4494/), should the domain of the side include all electronic games?  I'm not sure how far this would extend beyond pinball and other arcade games.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious question is *why*?

Stack Exchange isn't Yahoo! Answers or Quora: not *every* topic needs to be covered. If something isn't covered by existing sites, it's perfectly okay.

And we're not hurting from traffic or lack of quality questions that [dooms more specialized sites on the network](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/). We have our hands full already with *just* video game questions.

So what benefit do we get from muddying up the current scope to include non-video games? Is there an installed base of electronic game experts here? For that matter, where's the cultural overlap between video gamers and electronic gamers?

If there's a big push to have an electronic games site on Area 51, it's going to get shut down, and it's demonstrable that electronic gamers consider themselves to be video gamers (in the sense that we do here on Gaming: i.e., they enjoy console/mobile/desktop video games and will ask/answer questions about them), sure.

Otherwise, this is needless scope creep and boo to that. We should be [jealous of our site's purpose and scope](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/) and only expand it if it's absolutely going to be a win for what we're already doing here. I don't see how expanding to electronic games helps that.

Comment: @NickT Arcade games have far more in common with the site's scope than other electronic games (presumably this includes things like slot machines, video poker machines, pachinko, etc. right?) But in terms of demonstrable demand: if we changed our scope based on what 2 or 3 people want, ITG and Game Recommendations would still be on-topic. Where's the Area 51 proposal? Where are all the questions about electronic games? Where's the proof people who play those games consider themselves video gamers?

Comment: @NickT You're trying to say electronic games should be on-topic here: show something, *anything* that reasonably demonstrates that people who are electronic games enthusiasts consider themselves to be video gamers or that video gamers consider electronic games as part of the same field. Where's the synergy between the two topics? "Because they wouldn't get a site otherwise" by itself is a crappy reason and [isn't how SE defines the scopes of sites](http://stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @NickT I would agree if that were the case, but you haven't really demonstrated that. Are there other video game communities where pinball et al are welcome? Have we had a lot of pinball-related questions or confused people who get tripped up by this site being exclusively about video games? Is there an Area 51 proposal in the works about these types of games that's about to get shut down?

Comment: I agree, this is a slippery slope.  Pretty soon, you'll be arguing for adding stuff like skee ball and foosball

Comment: @yx. my end-game in all this is to get game-rec questions to be on-topic again, but not before cooking and gardening.

Comment: @yx., note that skee ball has already been mentioned in the linked pinball discussion ...