# Is Namco's F-1 (1976) in-scope?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

Namco's [F-1 (1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-1_(arcade_game)) electro-mechanical arcade racing game bears such strong resemblance to a "modern" video game that I'm wondering if it should be considered on-topic. The game itself is certainly likely to appeal to video game players, and was also made by a company now famous for "true" racing video games. The only major difference between this game and games like Pole Position and Ridge Racer is that F-1 generates its screen output [through a set of lights, mirrors, gears, and physical props](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1WSYdn1b8I) rather than by sending an electronic video output signal to a display.

Is F-1 enough of a video game to qualify as in-scope for this site, or does a game need to have a "true" video output signal to qualify?

I know that we have a Meta question about [pinball machines](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4494/161932), with the current vote tallies being barely in favor of off-topicality, but electro-mechanical racing games are (IMHO) much closer in look and feel to today's video games than their electro-mechanical pinball cousins are.

One argument could be that this game is too simplistic to be worthy of the label of video game. The scenery repeats after only a few seconds, and there is no level progression. My response to that is that it is no less complex than [Pong (1972)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong), and Pong is unquestionably on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

I personally think its On topic.

You have a bunch of controls that will affect a screen you are looking at. Thats enough of a game to me.

Pinball is also, IMO, but I can see it as further into the gray zone because Pinball is a physical game, where the only screen you interact with is for whatever your score is.

Comment: I disagree pinball is on topic.  I'm also weirdly on the fence about this Namco F1 _thing_. I marvel at its ingenuity, but its more mechanical than it is electronic it seems - drawing more similarities to something like pinball than a video game or other "games" you'd find at Arcades like a coin pusher (not the best comparison but I couldn't think of another example).  That screen you speak of is really a projection from what I can tell of the circular disc that spins around in the machine, blown up to a larger size presumably by the witchcraft magic of mirrors (I am assuming).

Comment: I wont deny that both are in a gray zone and thus, your mileage may vary. Personally, I would consider most of the things that are in arcades to be video games. But I know that falls apart because technically, UFO machines and coin pushers would be video games, in my definition. And they definitely are not.

Comment: Games like this, which are in some ways comparable to a carnival stand, like, say, shooting rubber ducks and such, surely deserve a place to live. But they're fairly specialized and niche. It seems like they'd be ok here as a dedicated stack exchange site is unlikely.